Testing Login function using Cypress on Chorme always get error 400 - Bad Request
I'm a new to Cypress and i want to test a login function by Cypress. Everything goes well but when i click the continue button, all i get is error 400. This error only occurs in Chorme, i have try this on Edge, Electron and successfully. Anyone could point that i have missed something? Thank you so much!
I already researched and i think the problem is from cookies and oauth. I have tried some way but still failed. Here is my code:
cy.visit("http://localhost:3000/");

cy.get("#menu-icon").should("be.visible");
cy.get("#menu-icon").click();

cy.contains("a", "Đăng nhập").should("be.visible");
cy.contains("a", "Đăng nhập").click();

cy.get("a").children().contains("span", "Đăng nhập bằng Google").parent().should("be.visible");
cy.get("a").children().contains("span", "Đăng nhập bằng Google").parent().click();

cy.origin("https://accounts.google.com/", () =\> {
const email = "email@gmail.com";
const password = "password";

cy.get("#identifierId").should("be.visible");
cy.get("#identifierId").type(email).should("have.value", email);

cy.get("button").children().contains("span", "Next").parent().should("be.visible");
cy.get("button").children().contains("span", "Next").parent().click();

Cypress.on(
  "uncaught:exception",
  (err) =>
    !err.message.includes("ResizeObserver loop") &&
    !err.message.includes("Error in protected function")
);

cy.get("#password > .aCsJod > .aXBtI > .Xb9hP > .whsOnd").should("be.visible");
cy.get("#password > .aCsJod > .aXBtI > .Xb9hP > .whsOnd")
  .type(password)
  .should("have.value", password);

cy.get("button").children().contains("span", "Next").parent().should("be.visible");
cy.get("button").children().contains("span", "Next").parent().click();

cy.get("button").children().contains("span", "Continue").parent().should("be.visible");
cy.get("button").children().contains("span", "Continue").parent().click();

I have read that {cy.session} or {cy.request} could solve this error but i don't know how start. Please help me!
